# How to pass data through stack navigation to a specific screen on react native tabs?

Tags: react-native

I'm creating a bottom tabs in react native, which will have two screens Home and News.
But first, user will need to Sign In and the users data will be passed from the login screen to Home screen. How do i pass those data. By using

```
navigation.navigate('Home', {Name: Name});
```

I can successfuly retrieve the data in Homescreen, if I just use two screen(Login and Home in a stack). However, when I change to navigate to the tabs(which includes Home and News), it doesnt work with error 'Undefined is not an object(evaluating 'route.params.Name'.
May you guys show me which part did I miss?

Here's the app.js code.

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import HomeScreen from './homescreen';
import NewsScreen from './newsscreen';
import LoginScreen from './loginscreen';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
function MyTabs() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="News" component={NewsScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

const LoginStack = createStackNavigator();
function App() {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <LoginStack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}
        initialRouteName="Login">
          <LoginStack.Screen name="Login"component={LoginScreen}/>
          <LoginStack.Screen name="MyTabs" component={MyTabs} />
        </LoginStack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
}
export default App;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Following is the homescreen code:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default function HomeScreen({route, navigation}) {
    var Name = route.params.Name;
    
    return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>{Name}</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

And finally here's the login code:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

export default function LoginScreen({navigation}) {
    const Name = 'Boy';
    const login = () => {
         navigation.navigate('MyTabs', {Name: 'Boy'});}

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>LoginScreen</Text>
      <TouchableOpacity 
                    onPress={login}
                    ><Text
                        >LOGIN</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
})
```

I'm trying to learn how to pass data from a screen to another screen, in which the screen is located inside a tab stack. I hope you guys can understand the question and provide me with your opinion and solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Output:**

[image]

It needed just this little modification in `MyTabs` component:

```
function MyTabs({ navigation, route }) {
  const { name } = route.params;
  console.log(name);
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={() => <HomeScreen name={route.params.name} />}
      />
      <Tab.Screen name="News" component={NewsScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Here is the working solution:

**App.js**

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import HomeScreen from './home';
import NewsScreen from './newscreen';
import LoginScreen from './login';
// You can import from local files
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function MyTabs({ navigation, route }) {
  const { name } = route.params;
  console.log(name);
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Home"
        component={() => <HomeScreen name={route.params.name} />}
      />
      <Tab.Screen name="News" component={NewsScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

const LoginStack = createStackNavigator();
function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <LoginStack.Navigator
        screenOptions={{ headerShown: true }}
        initialRouteName="Login">
        <LoginStack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
        <LoginStack.Screen name="MyTabs" component={MyTabs} />
      </LoginStack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**LoginScreen**

```js
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import React from "react";

export default function LoginScreen({ navigation }) {
  const Name = 'Name From Login Screen';
  const login = () => {
    console.log("hi");
    navigation.navigate('MyTabs', { name : Name });
  }
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.bottomView}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={login} style={styles.button}>
            <Text style={styles.textStyle}>LOGIN</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  
}
```

**Home.js**

```js
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import React from "react";
export default function HomeScreen({route, navigation, name}) {
  console.log("***",name)

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.name}>{name}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Working [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@xeteke8423/humiliated-pudding) example.

Comment: Hi Ketan Ramteke, now I've tried to make a little modification to the homescreen, in which I want to add a homestack navigation to a homedetails. I tried to pass the data to the homestack navigator before sending it to the homescreen. But, sadly the data isnt being transferred, and maybe i crashed the apps. Can you please help to see which part did I miss? Ive made the apps on ur expo snack, by following this link. https://snack.expo.io/@fahmijaafar/humiliated-pudding

Answer (score 0):

It's a little complicated to explain react native screens once you start combining bottomtabnavigator and stack navigator and even drawernavigation.

you may need to create stack navigation inside tab navigation like this.

```
//creating a separate stack within your tab
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator()
const HomeStackNavigator = () => {

return (

        <HomeStack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}
        initialRouteName="HomeScreen">
          <HomeStack.Screen name="Home"component={HomeScreen}/>
        </HomeStack.Navigator>
      )
}

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
function MyTabs() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName="HomeStackNavigator">
      <Tab.Screen name="HomeStackNavigator" component={HomeStackNavigator} />
      <Tab.Screen name="News" component={NewsScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

I believe, different navigators doesn't really talk to each other well. If you are using different navigator be prepare to nest stack navigators inside them.

The idea is, the parent of each display component should be a stack navigator. This will also allow you to better control your screenOptions.